# Instagram Public API returning error code 429

Tags: php, wordpress, graphql, instagram

I have the following code in a WordPress site and the response that I get back has `429: Too many requests`. Has anyone else run into this issue before and found a way around it?

- I'm nowhere near the max of 200 per hour, I've only tried it a few times so that shouldn't be an issue either.
- I'm able to retrieve a response without being authenticated in a private browser when I navigate to `https://www.instagram.com/google.com/?__a=1` so I know this isn't an authentication issue.

```php
static function bk_read_count_social( $data, $social_type, $apiKey = '' ) {
  if($social_type == 'instagram') {
    $username = 'google';
    $publicApiUrl = 'https://www.instagram.com/'.$username.'/?__a=1';

    $response = wp_remote_get($publicApiUrl);

    // 429 - Too Many Requests
    if ($response['response']['code'] !== 429) {
      $instagramArgs['followers'] = $response['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count'];
      $instagramArgs['username']  =  $username;
    } else {
      console_log('Unable to retrieve Instagram API');
      console_log($response);
      $instagramArgs['followers'] = '';
      $instagramArgs['username']  =  $username;
    }

    return $instagramArgs;
}
```

Comment: How is this code called by WordPress. Could you include more details to give context?

Comment: @HowardE, I updated the code a bit. It's called inside of a function and I have a `console_log` function that just logs it out the same as JS that I've been using to verify.

Comment: What wordpress action or filter is triggering the function? How can you console_log output if you're not in a javascript function?  I would try using `error_log(print_r($response, true));` and see what gets into the php error log.

Comment: @HowardE I know for a fact that it is getting triggered because I was able to verify with `console_log('hello world')`. As for my `console_log` I have a function that converts it from php to js because that's what I am more familiar with.
```function console_log($output, $with_script_tags = true) {
  $js_code = 'console.log(' . json_encode($output, JSON_HEX_TAG) . ');';
  if ($with_script_tags) {
    $js_code = '<script>' . $js_code . '</script>';
  }
  echo $js_code;
}```